# Putting labels next to vline per group using ggplot and facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

[image]I am trying to draw up a graph using ggplot and facet_wrap.

```
library(ggplot2)

year <- rep(2014:2015, length.out = 10000)
group <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
value <- sample(10000, replace = T)
dta1 <- data.frame(year = year, group = group, value = value)

dta2 <- data.frame( group = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6) , cut = c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000))

merged <- merge(dta1, dta2, by="group")

ggplot(merged, aes(x=value))+
  geom_histogram(fill="red")+
  facet_wrap(~ group, scales="free")+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = cut), color="black")+
  geom_text(data=data.frame(merged$cut), aes(label = 'T1 =', x = data.frame(merged$cut), y = Inf),
            hjust = 0, vjust = 1)
```

I managed to draw up individual vlines per group. Now I would like to :

1. place a label next to each vline that reads "T1 = 'the value of the cut'". So for example for group 1 that would read "T1 = 1000", for group 2 that would be "T1 = 2000", etc.
2. I would like this to be next to the vline on the top of the graph. Note that the frequencies are very different in my original data, so one my have a maximum of 10,000, the other might be only 100. This is why I use scales="free".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for.

1. Making use of `dplyr::distinct` create a helping data frame which contains only the values needed for the the vline and the labels, i.e. the `group` identifier and the `cut` value.
2. This helping df can then be passed as `data` argument to both the `geom_vline` and the `geom_text`. You could create your label via `label = paste0('T1 = ', cut)`

```r
library(ggplot2)

year <- rep(2014:2015, length.out = 10000)
group <- sample(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
value <- sample(10000, replace = T)
dta1 <- data.frame(year = year, group = group, value = value)

dta2 <- data.frame( group = c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6) , cut = c(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000))

merged <- merge(dta1, dta2, by="group")

df_vline <- dplyr::distinct(merged, group, cut)

ggplot(merged, aes(x=value))+
  geom_histogram(fill="red")+
  facet_wrap(~ group, scales="free")+
  geom_vline(data = df_vline, aes(xintercept = cut), color="black")+
  geom_text(data = df_vline, aes(x = cut, label = paste0('T1 = ', cut), y = Inf),
            hjust = 0, vjust = 1) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]